# Using Case or IF in TSQL Where clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case

I am trying to write logic for my where clause that essentially filters out two IDs based on a function.

Here is what I've written:

```
CASE
        WHEN e.BOOLcolumn <> 1
        THEN o.idType NOT IN ('G','C')
        ELSE RETURN
        END
```

For some reason I am returning an error on CASE and the NOT IN portions.  This is on a Stored Procedure in the Where clause.  My goal is that if my boolean is true, then the sproc should run like normal, and if it is false, then ('G','C') should not be in it.

I am a super novice in this and Google hasn't given me much regarding the use...I just don't know how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show the full sql statement you have. It is hard to understand what you really want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `CASE` at all if you just want to "filter out two IDs"?

```
WHERE e.column = 1 OR o.idType NOT IN ('G','C')
```

Comment: Because those ID's only need to be filtered out if my e.column <> 1.

Comment: That e.column is a Boolean and if it is false, then those ID's need to not go anywhere, if it is true, they need to go like normal.

Comment: @PapaNer: have a look at my modified answer. I've included the `column` check-

Comment: I think this is it!  I thank you for that.  I thought I'd be writing an IF statement, and then I saw that CASE was usually the way to go, and I didn't even consider doing a check....I am a novice, haha!  It takes a long time for my report to run after this sproc is updated...if it all works I'll give you the checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `WHERE` clause you're looking for:

```
WHERE e.BOOLcolumn = 1
    OR o.idType NOT IN ('G', 'C')
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I guess that this is not what OP wants. If i understand his try correctly he wants to apply the `NOT IN ('G','C')`-check only if `e.column <> 1`. **Edit** Ok, now you've used my query ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's the case with my clause, the check on `idType` is only made if the `BOOLcolumn <> 1`

Comment: Your query originally was: `WHERE o.column <> 1 AND o.idType NOT IN ('G', 'C')`. That didn't work as desired because it didn't include records with `o.column=1`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oky i understand your remark, in fact i immediately edited my post and your comment has been posted just in-between ;-)